# For what security reasons does Joomla add table prefixes?

Tags: php, mysql, prefix

What do table prefixes do regarding security?

When I install Joomla on localhost, it always generates unique table prefixes "for security reason". Why?

Comment: I guess that it is issuing a `CREATE TABLE` request with a name containing an appropriate, perhaps "random", prefix. Then, SQL injections might be harder....

Comment: because joomla is open source where everyone can have the same table names if there isn't a generated prefix, much harder to guess and exploit the tables.

Answer (score 2):

The random prefix makes it hard for a SQL Injection attack to guess valid table names.

These attacks work by inserting SQL code into user input fields. These can sometimes trick the backend server into executing additional SQL commands. If the attacker doesn't know the table names, then they can't write valid SQL to inject in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Attackers can rely on consistencies from application to application and if your table names have a unique prefix it's almost like having another type of password since the attacker can't see what you named your tables.

Otherwise, if they know your table names and they find a way to inject SQL through a known exploit, they can use the table names in the query to manipulate and or dump all your data.